# Will I be able to update the (optional) application icon after registering an application?

Tags: support, icons

The [Register Your Application](https://stackapps.com/apps/register) form allows for the (optional) submission of an application icon. Presumably this can be updated after registration via [Manage API keys](https://stackapps.com/apps)? I'd be surprised if not, of course, but I'd be happy if someone could confirm this so the world wouldn't need to see my untalented design and artwork forever ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm it (although i've never tried it :) )!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works fine. In fact, this reminded me to change my app registration to include the new website URL.